# i want to search strings from domain file in log file...for reading two files i used nested loops...incorrect output

Tags: java, android

```
while((sline= bbr.readLine()) != null) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if (line.contains(sline)){
            tracker.append(line); tracker.append("\n  ");tracker.append("\n  ");    
            String track = new String(tracker.toString()); 
            writeToFile(c,track,"trackingInfo.txt");
        }
    }// end of while1
}// end of while2
br.close();
bbr.close();
```

I use the nested loops first for reading domain file and second for the logfile. But for the first string from domain file it searches whole log file but not for the other strings in domain file.

Comment: By the time `br.readLine()` is executed by the second entry in your domain file the BufferedReader is at the end of the log file. Rather break the reading of your log file into another method. Keeping in mind the idea is not very efficient you may want to rather read the domain file first, storing the string you are scanning and only read the log file once and scan that one line for every entry which you read from the domain file

Comment: check out BufferedReader mark and reset if you want to reuse the same buffered reader

Comment: i have used different buffer readers for the two files but the first while loop executes only one time for only the first line... because the pointer is now at the end of the file.I dont no how to read again from start of the file.mark and reset are the good option but my file size is very large reseting the buffer doesnt work here.i think i have to use hash set or random access file,reopening is the another option but doesnot seems good in performance.Thank you for the help.